# Saxon 9 parser and indent="no" - How to remove 'pretty-print'?

Tags: xml, xslt

Setting indent="no" has no effect with Saxon 9.  I guess it is optional in the spec; it isn't really a bug or anything with Saxon.  Is there any way to remove the "pretty print"?  We save off the XML and it is quite a bit bigger with all the indents.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

The reason there is still indentation without including the above xslt instruction, is that whitespace-only nodes get copied.